# Display all tables in phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

How can I display all tables of a Database in phpMyAdmin ? I would like to display more tables in below images.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to config.inc.php file in the PHPMyAdmin root folder:

and change this line

```
$cfg['MaxTableList'] = 250;
```

to how many you actually want.
Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks @Andrei Fiordean. I am using Linux Mint 19. I could not find this in `config.inc.php`. Thanks.